# Format from ticks to date

Tags: c#

I am needing to transfer some logs which were timestamped in ticks to an XML document. I would prefer the timestamps to be more Specific such as "July 14, 2009 10:18:04 pm"

I was planning to using something along the line of:

```
DateTime logDate = DateTime.Parse(logText);
logDate.ToString("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

I figured this would be OK as DateTime.Now.Ticks is how you can get ticks. It is however returning that it is not a proper DateTime format. during setting logDate.

I am sure there is a simple solution but I just can't come across it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If `logText` is a string, you can convert it to long (Int64) and use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326681(VS.71).aspx):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse(logText));
```

Comment: `long` is an alias for Int64.

Comment: @Lee, exactly, long is a C# language specific keyword that is equivalent to the .NET Framework Int64 type

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'logText' is the ticks, try:

```
DateTime logDate = new DateTime(logText);
```