# How to convert time string in milliseconds to DateTime object in c#?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, converters

I have the time in milliseconds as a string like this: `229935440730121`
How to convert this string to a `DateTime` object.

Thanks

### Update

Sorry, The correct string is : `1423509923000` and should be 2/9/15 7:25:23 PM after conversion. It's a time string received from an telemetry device.

Comment: Presumably it's a number of milliseconds since an epoch - probably the unix epoch? So first parse it to a `long`, and then add that number of milliseconds to a `DateTime` representing that epoch...

Comment: Seems a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336932/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-format-in-c

Comment: Tim - that will throw an overflow exception. You'll need `long.Parse` for a number that large.

Comment: `229935440730121` milliseconds is about `7286` years. Check if you have computed the argument right.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: perhaps it's already the sum, f.e. of man-days. However, it sounds as if a `TimeSpan` is more appropriate anyway. For example: `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(229935440730121)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Milliseconds is a *duration*, not a *time*.  You can convert it to a `TimeSpan` easily:

```
string ms = "229935440730121";
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(double.Parse(ms));
```

To convert to a `DateTime` you need to know the reference point from which the span was measured, then just add the `TimeSpan` to that date:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;  // for example only
dt += ts;  // add the timespan to the date
```

In your example, that number of milliseconds represents *over 7,280 years*, so it's not clear what the reference point should be.

Comment: The correct string was 1423509923000. And this is the given number of milliseconds that have passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00, Coordinated Universal Time. I replaced `DateTime.MinValue` with `DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00")` and it works perfect. Thanks