# converting datetime object from json

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have following code

```
  var res = from c in model.Data 
            select new object[] { c.Id, c.Time, c.Name };
```

this res variable is sent as json object.

Time is DateTime property.
I'm fetching this json objects in the view like following

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Home/AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "ID",
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                return '<a href=\"Details/' +
                                oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                            }
                        },
                        { "sName": "Time" },
                        { "sName": "Name" }
                    ]
        });
    });
```

Page is rendered with datetime fields like `/Date(1346996934000)/`

What is the best way to convert this, on the server side or in the view and how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Do you need help converting all those numbers in Date() to a readable date string?

Comment: @Gabriel Florit that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that number the date in ticks? If that's the case, then

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(long.Parse(1346996934000));
```

Found that here: [Format from ticks to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129410/format-from-ticks-to-date)

This would be converted to: *Fri Sep 07 2012 01:48:54* in GMT-4 timezone.

This is a solution I for doing it in JavaScript, found here: http://deekshadev.blogspot.com/2011/03/convert-ticks-to-date-object.html

```
//convert the event day to a date object
var startticks = new Date(ticks * 1000);

//convert today to ticks will be in milliseconds
var todayticks = new Date().getTime();

var diff = startticks - todayticks;
var days = Math.floor(diff/(24*60*60*1000));
var hours = (diff/(60*60*1000)) % 24;
var mins = (diff/(60*1000)) % 60;
Here ticks was in seconds, so multiplying it with 1000 to convert to milliseconds.
```

If that date is only needed for display, I wouldn't do it on the server level. I'd convert on the client and display it as needed.