# Convert a Date to a Long or its binary form to write to a file?

Tags: vb.net, date

How can I go about converting a date to a long?  Casting it doesn't work :/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every DateTime structure has a method called [ToBinary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and a method called [FromBinary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that according to MSDN

> Use the ToBinary method to convert the value of the current DateTime
>   object to a binary value.  Subsequently, use the binary value and the
>   FromBinary method to recreate the original DateTime  object.

The return value from ToBinary() is a long value, and the input value for FromBinary is again a long value.

Comment: Nice!  Didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of ticks since `DateTime.MinValue` which is represented by the `DateTime` object.  You can then, when you load it from file, you can recreate the `DateTime` object using the constructor which takes a number of ticks.  For instance:

```
Dim ticks As Long = myDate.Ticks
Dim myDate2 As Date = New Date(ticks)
```

Comment: +1 Ticks works as well, but perhaps the shown constructor doesn't take account of timezone. Really never have to worry about timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Well In Java, we might do something like this :

```
            String str_date="11-June-07";
            DateFormat formatter ; 
            Date date ; 
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
            date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
            long longDate=date.getTime();
            System.out.println("Today is " +longDate );
```

Try this in VB.net :

```
      Dim d As Date = Today
       MsgBox(d.ToOADate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ticks property, assuming that's the Long value you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx

See also:

[Format from ticks to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129410/format-from-ticks-to-date)